# Can Grafana Mimir works as a permanent storage solution for Grafana Loki?

Tags: grafana-loki, grafana-mimir

I am using Grafana Loki for log monitoring. Currently, I have a grafana agent in static mode installed in a remote linux machine and configured the required logs file to remote write to Loki.

Grafana Loki is again installed in a remote linux machine. The log monitoring is successful. However, I need to see a permanent storage solution for the logs collected by Grafana Loki. Here I want use only Grafana family for long term storage instead of using Cloud services like S3, ABS, GCS.

Can Grafana Mimir be integrated with Grafana Loki for permanent storage solution ? If yes, can anyone let me know the process ?

Comment: How can you ingest log into metric storage (Mimir)?